# Update object inside the array in mongoDb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I am working on MongoDB for update object value which is inside of the array in MongoDB collection.

My collection is like

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("59b7e839200a5c00ee2d2851"),
  "player": "New",
  "playesList": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("59b2a4f749fee40959e556d3"),
      "name": "abcd",
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("59b2a4f749fee40959e556d4"),
      "name": "pqrs",
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to update the name of the player whose id is `59b2a4f749fee40959e556d3`(i mean first player name currently it was abcd), whose collection id is `59b7e839200a5c00ee2d2851` and player `New`.

So I am trying to update with this query

```
play.update(
      {
          '_id': '59b7e839200a5c00ee2d2851',
          'player': 'new',
          'playesList._id': '59b2a4f749fee40959e556d3'
      },
      {
          '$set': { 'playesList.$.name': 'wxyz' }
      },
      function(error, success) {
         console.log(error, success);
      }
)
```

But here I got in console like `null { ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0 }` and value cann't update into collection.
Please help me how can solve this error.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11):

Objects (documents) inside the array in MongoDB collection are called - [**subdocuments**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

In this case, to update specific subdocument with its own `_id`, you can use Mongoose [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) method:

```
play.findOneAndUpdate({
    "_id": "59b7e839200a5c00ee2d2851",
    "playesList._id": "59b2a4f749fee40959e556d3"
}, {
    "$set": {
        "playesList.$.name": "something"
    }
}, function(error, success) {

})
```

first you are need to find document in collection with:

```
"_id": "59b7e839200a5c00ee2d2851"
```

then find subdocument by its `_id` using second parameter:

```
"playesList._id": "59b2a4f749fee40959e556d3"
```

and when you find the subdocument that you want to update, use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator to set new value to `name` property of found subdocument:

```
"$set": {
    "playesList.$.name": "something"
}
```

Note that `findOneAndUpdate` returns previous state of updated document.

**Working example:**

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var router = require('express').Router()
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/stackoverflowanswer')
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

var PlayerSchema = new Schema({
    play: String,
    playersList: [{
        name: String
    }]
})

var Player = mongoose.model('Players', PlayerSchema)

app.use('/', router)

router.get('/add-player', function(req, res, next) {
    var player = new Player()

    player._id = "59b7e839200a5c00ee2d2851"
    player.play = "New"
    player.playersList.push({
        _id: "59b2a4f749fee40959e556d3",
        name: "abcd"
    }, {
        _id: "59b2a4f749fee40959e556d4",
        name: "pqrs"
    })

    player.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err

        res.json({
            message: 'Success'
        })
    })
})

router.get('/update-player', function(req, res, next) {
    Player.findOneAndUpdate({
        "_id": "59b7e839200a5c00ee2d2851",
        "playersList._id": "59b2a4f749fee40959e556d3"
    }, {
        "$set": {
            "playersList.$.name": "wxyz"
        }
    }, function(error, success) {
        if (error) throw error

        res.json({
            message: 'Success'
        })
    })
})

app.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Node.js listening on port ' + 8080)
})
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain why this answers the question. As a hi-rep user you should know that such answers are flagged as "low quality".

Answer (score 1):

```
play.findById('59b7e839200a5c00ee2d2851', (err, item) => {  
    // Handle any possible database errors
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {

        item.playesList.$.name = 'wxyz'

        // Save the updated document back to the database
        item.save((err, updated_item) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err)
            }
            res.status(200).send(updated_item);
        });
    }
});
```